# Which one is more correct?$V_y$ or $V_i$

Tags: general-topology, index-notation

In the theorem  $26.3 $: every compact  subspace  of a hausdorff space is closed

Munkre say that   the collection $\{V_y|y \in Y\}$  is  a covering of $Y$  by sets open in $X$

But many  authors  write  $
\{V_i\}_{i \in I
}$ is  an open cover of $Y$

Here  im confused    about Munkres style of writing .

$Y$ is not an index set  .$Y$ is a compact subspace of the hausdorff space $X $

So i think  Munkres  style of writing   is wrong.He should write like  this $\{V_y|y \in I\}$ .

I am confused in regards to these two writing  $\{V_y|y \in Y\}$ and $
\{V_i\}_{i \in I
}$
Which one is more correct?

Comment: Depending on how the $V_i$ are chosen, it could mean the same thing. Munkres' notation is typically reserved to mean "a neighborhood of $y$", whereas the other is just any collection of sets (could be the same as what Munkres has in mind). There are probably two competing thoughts here: Munkres wants to push you away from thinking about a typically discrete index variable $i$ to allow for more complicated spaces. The $i$ index variable might be an .. *eye* towards compactness and such where you can drop down to a finite set.

Comment: Any set can be used as an indexing set. It's just a way of labelling elements, and you can use pretty much whatever you want to do that.

Comment: If, for each point $y \in Y$, we have an open neighborhood $V_y$ of $y$, then $\{V_y \mid y \in Y\}$ is an open cover of $Y$.    If Munkres constructs such sets $V_y$ in that proof, he is OK.  But perhaps he is not claiming that every open cover of $V$ looks like that.

Comment: I don't have the book, but given the theorem being proven, Munkres presumably lets $Y$ be compact, $x \not\in Y$, and for each $y$ in $Y$ uses "Hausdorff" to pick disjoint open sets $U_{y}$ containing $x$ and $V_{y}$ containing $y$, so that $\{V_{y} : y \in Y\}$ is a covering of $Y$ by open sets. Of your two choices, the first is unambiguously correct.

Comment: It's not like there some special category of sets that serve as "index sets". An index set is just as set, used as the domain of a function. The notation $\{V_y \mid y \in Y\}$ can be thought of a function that associates, to each $y \in Y$, an object denoted $V_y$, and then collects all of those objects into one set.